# VBA Finding which Togglebuttons are true and copying it's captions to textboxes in another userform

Tags: vba, userform

I'm quite new at VBA coding and I need some help, please.

Basically I have 2 userforms one of which contains multiple Tooglebuttons that can be selected, up to 16, and another userform that contains 16 textboxes. What I need is when I press a button, the code will loop trough the first userform and find what Togglebuttons are selected and then the caption of these tooglebuttons will be the same text put on the textboxes, one caption each.

I've tried to do it myself but I haven't been able to loop trough both at the same time. With my code all the textboxes get the same caption

```
Sub tog()
Dim TBTrueCount As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim ctrl As Control
ck = 0

For i = 20 To 35 'number of the textboxes
For Each ctrl In Produtos.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "ToggleButton" Then
    TBTrueCount = TBTrueCount - CLng(ctrl.Value)
        Dim tggl As toggleButton
        Set tggl = ctrl
        If TBTrueCount > 16 Then 'max number of tooglebuttons selected
        ck = 1
        tggl.Value = False
        tggl.BackColor = vbButtonFace
        End If
        If tggl.Value = True Then
        tggl.BackColor = vbGreen
        Controle.Controle("TextBox" & i) = tggl.Caption
        End If
        
        If tggl.Value = False Then
        tggl.BackColor = vbButtonFace
        End If
    End If
Next ctrl
Next i



If ck = 1 Then
MsgBox "Selecionado numero máximo de Produtos"
End If
End Sub
```

I'm from Brazil so some words are in Portuguese. Excuse my english.

VBA Finding which Togglebuttons are true and copying it's captions to textboxes in another userform

Comment: Is this code in a userform, or a regular module?

Comment: It's in a userfom

Comment: Then the code I posted should work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd maybe do it like this:

```vb
Sub tog()
    Const MAX_SEL As Long = 16
    Dim ctrl As Control, txtNum As Long, col As New Collection
    
    'first collect all "true" toggle buttons
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls 'if this code is in `Produtos`
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "ToggleButton" Then
            ctrl.BackColor = IIf(ctrl.Value = True, vbGreen, vbButtonFace)
            If ctrl.Value = True Then col.Add ctrl
        End If
    Next ctrl
    
    If col.Count > MAX_SEL Then 'too many selected?
        MsgBox "Selecionado numero máximo (" & MAX_SEL & ") de Produtos"
    Else
        txtNum = 20
        For Each ctrl In col
            Controle.Controls("TextBox" & txtNum).Text = ctrl.Caption
            'Debug.Print ctrl.Caption
            txtNum = txtNum + 1
        Next ctrl
    End If
     
End Sub
```

It would be a little annoying for your users if you auto-uncheck some of their selections: better to let them do it.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Looks like I misunderstood the question. The below assumes that the toggles are linked to the textboxes (ToggleButton25 changes TextBox25) rather than the textboxes filling consecutively up to a max number.

Your `i` loop is incrementing separately from the ToggleButtons. If you manually increment `i` each time you find a ToggleButton it will match the associated TextBox.

```
Sub tog()
    Dim TBTrueCount As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ctrl As Control
    ck = 0
    i = 20

    For Each ctrl In Produtos.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "ToggleButton" Then
            Dim tggl As toggleButton
            TBTrueCount = TBTrueCount - CLng(ctrl.Value)
            Set tggl = ctrl

            If TBTrueCount > 16 Then 'max number of tooglebuttons selected
                ck = 1
                tggl.Value = False
            End If

            If tggl.Value = True Then
                tggl.BackColor = vbGreen
                Controle.Controle("TextBox" & i) = tggl.Caption
            Else
                tggl.BackColor = vbButtonFace
            End If

            i = i + 1 'increase i each time a ToggleButton is found
        End If
    Next ctrl

    If ck = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Selecionado numero máximo de Produtos"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The code works, but like you said it links the number of the tooglebutton to the number of the textbox. So it only fills the textboxes with the same numbers as the tooglebuttons. I have about 67 togglebuttons, of these only 16 can be selected and then the textboxes 20 to 35 would be filled.

Comment: Since you already got a proper answer from Tim Williams I decided not to edit mine. Move `i=i+1` to the end of the `tggl.Value = True` branch and replace `TBTrueCount > 16` with `i > 36` and it should work.